# how to fix failed avidemux installation

Tags: 14.04, package-management, avidemux

Using 14.04 64 bit, I tried to install avidemux 2.6.8 from

```
ppa:rebuntu16/avidemux+unofficial
```

Unfortunately, the installation

```
sudo apt-get install avidemux2.6-qt4
```

failed:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/avidemux2.6-common_2.6.8-1~ppa+trusty0_all.deb (–unpack):
trying to overwrite ‘/usr/share/man/man1/avidemux.1.gz’, which is also in package avidemux-common 1:2.5.4-0ubuntu14
```

Subsequent tries to install or remove something always bring up the following error messages:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 avidemux2.6-jobs : Depends: avidemux2.6-common but it is not going to be installed
 avidemux2.6-plugins-qt4 : Depends: avidemux2.6-qt4 (= 2.6.8-1~ppa+trusty0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

An `apt-get -f install`

tries to install the dependencies, but runs into the same problem.
The problem seems to come from duplicate files in the package which would overwrite each other during installation.

What to do? How can I repair the package system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `aptitude` solve the problem for you.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Start aptitude

```
sudo aptitude
```

In the bottom line problem solutions are offered.

[image]

Use <kbd>E</kbd> for Examine and <kbd>.</kbd> and/or <kbd>,</kbd> to move between proposed solutions

Apply with <kbd>!</kbd>

And Go with <kbd>G</kbd>

Comment: That does not work. The remove attempt brings up the same error message as described above.

Comment: New solution with `aptitude`

Comment: After disabling the ppa, I could successfully run "sudo apt-get -f install". Then, I was able to remove several packages of avidemux, and install aptitude. Using aptitude I cleaned up. Now trying to install from the ppa, again.

Comment: I had to disable the ppa to overcome the problem. "apt-get -f install" tries to solve the dependencies, and that ran into the same problem, again. Now, I have re-activated the ppa, and successfully installed avidemux 2.6.8. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: @hako Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: @hako No need to remove the PPA. Aptitude would have solved the problem.

Comment: Here "UBUNTU" forum and the usual "terminal install procedure" for UBUNTU is use `apt` command not `aptitude` (usual for Debian). So, please show a terminal sequence of commands that is valid as secure and reliable procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did not work for me (it gave the same error). What worked was [hako's](https://askubuntu.com/users/79455/hako) solution - remove the PPA repository by opening Ubuntu Software Center -> Edit menu -> Software Sources -> Other Software and then uncheck both the PPA records (including the source code link) for Avidemux. After this run the command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

to resolve this error.